# dotnet nuget restore says it's unable to find a package with a specific version, but in the same error messages says it has found it?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm attempting to restore packages in my project with

`dotnet restore`

And am receiving the (seemingly nonsensical) error message:

```
/code/modules-mobilebanking/Modules.MobileBanking.API/Modules.MobileBanking.API.csproj : error NU1102: Unable to find package ApplicationLogic.Contract with version (>= 1.1.0)
       /code/modules-mobilebanking/Modules.MobileBanking.API/Modules.MobileBanking.API.csproj : error NU1102:   - Found 2 version(s) in GitLab [ Nearest version: 1.1.0 ]
       /code/modules-mobilebanking/Modules.MobileBanking.API/Modules.MobileBanking.API.csproj : error NU1102:   - Found 0 version(s) in nuget.org
```

So it says it finds two versions of the package, one of which IS EXACTLY the version it says it's looking for. I have read/write access to the nuget source named `GitLab`, and about a dozen other packages are successfully restored from this nuget source.  I can also query the nuget source and verify that the package exists at two different versions:

```
{
"@type": "Package",
"authors": "",
"id": "ApplicationLogic.Contract",
"title": "ApplicationLogic.Contract",
"summary": "",
"totalDownloads": 0,
"verified": true,
"version": "1.1.0",
"versions": [
{
"@id": "https://gtlb.company.com/api/v4/projects/25/packages/nuget/metadata/ApplicationLogic.Contract/1.1.0.json",
"version": "1.1.0",
"downloads": 0
},
{
"@id": "https://gtlb.company.com/api/v4/projects/25/packages/nuget/metadata/ApplicationLogic.Contract/1.0.0.json",
"version": "1.0.0",
"downloads": 0
}
],
"tags": ""
}
```

Comment: Perhaps try resetting your nuget caches `dotnet nuget locals --clear all` or upgrading nuget itself `nuget.exe update -self`

Comment: I tried `dotnet nuget locals  all --clear` with no luck.  I'm on a mac, so I don't have `nuget.exe`.  My `dotnet nuget --version` is 6.3.1.1

Comment: Have you tried creating a new nuget config using `dotnet new nugetconfig` ?

Comment: Well, that appears to have worked.  Thanks.  Any ideas why it worked?  I've been using this nugetconfig successfully for almost 11 months now, every day.

Comment: If you can figure out how to reproduce the error, please report it to github.com/NuGet/Home. I remember this bug being reported once before, but without being able to reproduce it on my own machine, I don't know how to debug to find the root cause and fix the awful error message.